# Spark: Scala equivalent to Java df.filter()

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to know what is the equivalent in Scala to Spark Java function `filter`:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().parquet(xxx);
String filter = "SomeFilter";
df.filter(filter);
```

Normally `filter` should take a function as input in Scala, why it's taking a `string` in Java ?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same modulo syntax:

```
val df = sqlContext.read().parquet(xxx)
val filter = "SomeFilter"
df.filter(filter)
```

using [`def filter(conditionExpr: String): Dataset[T]`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@filter(conditionExpr:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]). Note that a `Dataframe` in the Scala Spark API is [just](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.package@DataFrame=org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]) a `Dataset[Row]`.

There's *also* an overload which takes a `Column` and an `@Experimental` one which takes a function.

> Normally filter should take a function as input in Scala, why it's taking a string in Java ?

`filter` is just a method name, it can take whatever arguments it's defined to. Here the string (or a `Column`) represents an SQL boolean condition.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I want to know what is the equivalent to df.show() in Java ? I want to put it in log so I need it to be string, but when I use showString() it shows unreadable characters